# The expectation only depends on its distribution

Tags: probability, expected-value

On a countable space $\Omega$, let $X$ be a real-valued random variable and the expectation of $X$ is
$$
E(X)=\sum_\omega X(\omega)P(\{ \omega\})
$$
$L^1$ is the space of real-valued random variables which have a finite expectation. The distribution of $X$ is
$$
P^X(A)=P(X^{-1}(A))=P(X\in A)
$$

I am trying to understand what it means that if $X\in L^1$, then **the expectation depends only on its distribution**? I don't really get it.

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote,

$E[X] = \sum X(\omega) P(\{\omega\})$.

This could be written differently as $E[X] = \sum xP(X=x)$.

This makes it easy to see that the expectation is determined by the distribution since $P(X=x) = P(X^{-1}(x))$ .